# to insert the values in database table without using interactive python shell in django 

Tags: python, django, linux, sqlite, ubuntu-10.04

My app name is search_keywords. As on creating this app, I wiil have one file called models.py
in which I have written this piece if code :

```
from django.db import models 

class Keywords(models.Model):
    file_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    frequency_count = models.IntegerField()
```

then add this app to INSTALLED_APPS and run python manage.py syncdb. On running this command , I will get a table automatically created in django. Then run python manage.py sql search_keywords. It will show the table as desired.

Then the next step is to run python manage.py shell.Instead of running this I want to insert the values in my table created through the python code that I have created.The code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#here skey.py is another file created by me and has the imported functions 
#in this code 
from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list 
str1 = raw_input("enter the word to be searched\n")
list = []
fo = open("xml.txt","r")

for i in range(count.__len__()):

    file = fo.readline()
    file = file.rstrip('\n')
    find_root_tags(file,str1,i) 

list.append((file,count[i]))

sorting_list(list)
fo.close()
```

I want to insert this list elements in the the table created by the django and that too after the function sorting_list has been called. The list contains the file name and it's count. e.g. list=[('books.xml','3'),('news.xml,'2')].

How can I do that?

Please Help.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Hey I have written the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#to tell django which settings module to use 
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

from search.models import Keywords 

from skey import find_root_tags, count, sorting_list

str1 = raw_input("enter the word to be searched\n")
list = []
fo = open("xml.txt","r")

for i in range(count.__len__()):

    file = fo.readline()
    file = file.rstrip('\n')
    find_root_tags(file,str1,i) 

    list.append((file,count[i]))

sorting_list(list)

for name, count in list:
    s = Keywords(file_name=name,frequency_count=count)
    s.save()

fo.close()
```

Here django_project = mysite #my project's name 
and app = search #my app's name

on running this code it gives me error :

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "call.py", line 7, in

from search.models import Keywords

ImportError: No module named search.models

and on including :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_django_project)
```

this in above code it gives error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "call.py", line 4, in

sys.path.insert(0,path_to_mysite)

NameError: name 'path_to_mysite' is not defined

Why?I have my project on the desktop and the above python code file as well.
Please Help!!

//////////////////////////////////////////
now it's giving me this error , please help.see it at : 
[error in accessing table created in django in the python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307928/error-in-accessing-table-created-in-django-in-the-python-code)

Comment: hey there is no-one who can help me at this . please guys I really need to know urgently . please help!!!

Comment: please someone help me at the second problem that I mentioned half hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be a probjem just importing your models and create object instances to persist to the database:

```
# setup sys.path first if needed
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_django_project)

# tell django which settings module to use
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'

# import application models
import test_app.models as m

# create and save db entries...
o = m.TestObject()
o.var = 'spam'
o.par = 1
o.save()
```

Comment: please tell me one more thing that the code you have given import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings', I  have to write these lines in my code mentioned above.

Comment: if you want to use django from a pyhton script outside of a django app, yes, you'll have to set it up first so django can find the configuration, and the directory of the django project must be in `sys.path`. more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/)

Comment: can you please look at my code that I have just edited and mentioned above. why is it giving such error?

Comment: Just replace `path_to_mysite` with the path to your project directory. It's complaining that the variable isn't set.

Answer (score 1):

For each element in your list, create an instance of `Keywords_Search`. After that, call `.save()` on each of them. For example:

```
for name, count in mylist:
    s = Keywords_Search(file_name=name, frequency_count=count)
    s.save()
```

Comment: can you please look at my code that I have just edited and mentioned above. why is it giving such error?

Answer (score 0):

First, there are few problems with your code (for example, you are calling methods that are built-ins, not to mention `count.__len__()`). Instead of trying to figure out what you are doing, here are the two recommended way to do this in django:

1. Django provides the functionality to [provide initial data for models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) in SQL, XML, YAML or JSON. This allows for automatic data insertion *everytime* you run syncdb. You don't have to run a command again.
2. Create a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it with `manage.py`

I'm assuming you have a file of keywords, and you want to search how many of the entered keyword is in the file.

Here is how you would create a custom management command that does this:

```
from collections import Counter
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from search.models import Keywords

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = 'search_string'
    help = 'Enter the search string'


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        file_contents = []
        with open('keyword_master.txt') as f:
            file_contents = [l for l in f.readlines() if l.rstrip('\n')]

        if not file_contents:
           raise CommandError("Cannot read keyword_master.txt")

        c = Counter(file_contents)

        for search_string in args:
            freq = c[search_string]
            Keywords.object.create(keyword=search_string,frequency_count=freq)
            self.stdout.write('Added %s freq for "%s"' % (freq,search_string))
```

Create a folder called `commands` inside any app. Inside this folder, create a blank file called `__init__.py`. In the same folder, save this file as "keyword_importer.py". So now you have:

```
/search
..__init__.py
../commands
.....__init__.py
.....keyword_importer.py
.....keyword_master.txt
```

Now run it with `python manage.py keyword_importer mykeyword`