# error in accessing table created in django in the python code

Tags: python, django, linux, sqlite, ubuntu-10.04

Now on writing path as sys.path.insert(0,'/home/pooja/Desktop/mysite'), it ran fine asked me for the word tobe searched and gave this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "call.py", line 32, in
>
> s.save()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 463, in save
>
> self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
>   force_update=force_update)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 524, in
>
> save_base
>
> manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists())):
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
>   line 562, in exists
>
> return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
>   line 441, in has_results
>
> return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
>   line 818, in execute_sql
>
> cursor.execute(sql, params)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py",
>   line 40, in execute
>
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)    File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py",
>   line 337, in execute
>        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
>
> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: search_keywords

Please help!!

Comment: Did you run command `syncdb` or migrate the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says: `no such table: search_keywords`, which is quite self-explanatory and means that there is no database table with such name. So:

1. You may be using relative path to db file in `settings.py`, which resolves to a different db depending on place where you execute the script. Try to use absolute path and see if it helps.
2. You have not synced your models with the database. Run `manage.py syncdb` to generate the database tables.

Comment: you were right. But I did create the tables before . I don't what happened why was'nt it accepting that one. Now I again I did all those steps , and it's working. Thanks , anyway :)